# Is that possible to delay UpdatePanel update on the client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an old system which uses UpdatePanels of asp.net

After the postback is completed, we know that the inside of UpdatePanel is updated

Can i delay this update somehow on the client side ? is that possible?

So it will be like, when the postback is started, i set a javascript datetime object on the client side

Once the postback is completed, and the data is returned from the server, before updating the client side interface, i check how many miliseconds has passed and I delay the update of the client side until certain miliseconds has passed

is this possible?

asp.net 4.5 c#

Answer (score 0):

You would have to delay it before sending the POST.  Since they used Update Panels, you can't modify the the AJAX callback function that is generated by ASP.NET.

To delay it pre-POST, add a JavaScript click event handler for the Update Panel's trigger control(s) and put a delay in it.

Comment: yes but this is not a solution for me since the server delay is unknown. i guess what i want is not possible

Comment: Yep, not possible.  If it's really important, you can switch from Update Panel to jQuery AJAX.  jQuery AJAX is really quite simple and has much less overhead.

Comment: do you know which function is used to update the interface? perhaps we can override when will be this function called after the response is received.